# Search window visible even after search result selection using JMeter

Tags: javascript, wicket, jmeter

In the application I am testing, we have a "hyperlink picker" to open a client search window.As we click on the searched client in search window.The window is closed and client information is shown in the associated picker.
But when I do the same with JMeter, on click on searched client, picker is populated with the client value but search window does not disappear, as it was supposed to be.(As evident from response data).
I am using POST request to select the client and application is built in wicket.

Comment: @Satyam Koyani - have u ever came across such a problem ?

Comment: I am not aware of wicket framework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does the search window disappear based on some script in the page itself? 
As far as i know Jmeter does not actually execute any scripts in the response pages. So this could explain what you are seeing.